# VBA IF cell VALUE LENGTH criteria

Tags: vba, if-statement, string-length

I have a code:

```
IF s LIKE "UZL.*" AND s LIKE "*.ENG" THEN
```

It evaluates if cell value starts with "UZL." and ends with ".ENG" but I would like to change those second criteria ".ENG" to be cell length =16 symbols. So it's like

```
If s Like "UZL.*" And cell value length =16 Then
```

Can someone please say what would be the code for that?

Full code:

```
Dim vDB As Variant
Dim rngDB As Range
Dim s As String, sReplace As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = Sheets("BOM")

On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("BOM").ShowAllData
 
With Ws
    Set rngDB = .Range("E2", .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
vDB = rngDB
For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    s = vDB(i, 1)
    If s Like "UZL.*" And s Like "*.ENG" Then
        sReplace = Me.LanguageBox.Value
        s = Replace(s, "ENG", sReplace)
        vDB(i, 1) = s
    End If
Next i
rngDB = vDB
```

Workbook: https://easyupload.io/37tztt

Comment: You probably want the [`Len` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function), which takes a string and returns the number of characters in the string.

Comment: I've been trying LEN function for a while but it doesn't work cuz I probably don't know how to write it properly. WHat I've got is

     If s Like "UZL.*" And Len(rng) = 16 Then

What is my mistake?

Comment: `Len` works on strings, not on `Range` objects; is `rng` a string or a `Range` object? Also, you should edit those details into your question. Also, you say _it doesn't work_; you should probably specify how you know it doesn't work; is it a runtime error? a compilation error? does the code return the wrong result?

Comment: How do I know? Well because I see absolutely no change... no errors and no result at all.

DIM rng As Range

Comment: Again, you don't want to use `Len` on `rng`, because `rng` holds a `Range` object. You want to use it on `s`, the string which you've extracted from the cell.

Comment: I updated the post with an actual workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a super expert on this matter but I believe you can use LEN function to obtain the text length.

I believe this should work:

```
If s Like "UZL.*" And Len(s.value) = 16 Then
```

UPDATE:

I've made a test locally and len function should be ok if s variable is in fact a string:

```
Sub Teste()
    
    s = "test"
    
    'First test
    If s Like "tes*" And Len(s) >= 4 Then
        Debug.Print "First Test: OK"
    End If
    
    'Second test
    If s Like "tes*" And Len(s) < 4 Then
        Debug.Print "Second Test: OK"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Second Test: NOK"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Console Output:

- First Test: OK
- Second Test: NOK

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything at all. Would you like to see a workbook?

Comment: I've updated the answer check if value will return the cell text if so then the LEN function should work fine.

Comment: Dim s As String

New code returns an error: "Invalid qualifier" on that "s"

Comment: If you're setting s As String then you don't need to get the value (s.value) the s variable should be enougth. Please update your post and share the full VBA scipt.

Comment: I can't run your code locally. Although I've made a test locally to the length function and it should be ok if the s variable is in fact a string. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I updated the post with the actual Workbook. Please check it out. Code should work infinite times.